# AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'max'

Tags: python, c++, function, ctypes

I am trying to call a C++ function from the Python.And here is code from python side:

```
from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libfoo.so')

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = lib.Foo_new()

    def bar(self):
        lib.Foo_bar(self.obj)

    def max(self,num1,num2):
        lib.Foo_max(self.obj)

f = Foo()
f.bar()
f.max(3,5)
```

Which is giving attribute error as :

```
Hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Linkcpp.py", line 16, in <module>
    f.max(3,5)
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'max'
```

Please tell what is correction in above code.

My c++ code is foo.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
    public:
        void bar(){
            std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
        }

        int max(int num1,int num2) 
        {
          // local variable declaration
          int result;

          if (num1 > num2)
            result = num1;
          else
            result = num2;

          return result; 
        }
};

extern "C" {
    int num1;
    int num2;
    Foo* Foo_new(){ return new Foo(); }
    void Foo_bar(Foo* foo){ foo->bar(); }
    int Foo_max(Foo* foo){ return foo->max(num1,num2); }
}
```

And I am compiling the C++ code by the following commands :

> g++ -c -fPIC foo.cpp -o foo.o
>
> g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so -o libfoo.so  foo.o

Comment: Presumably you've verified that `Foo.max` *does* exist, right?

Comment: The paths for `num1` and `num2` are very unclear. The ones provided don't arrive in the C++ code; the C++ code uses uninitialized fields. That is not related to the current problem, but will be related with the next one.

Comment: Also, you're truncating the instance pointer to 32-bit, which will segfault in a 64-bit process. Set `lib.Foo_new.restype = ctypes.c_void_p`. Then either set `argtypes` for every function that uses it or wrap the result in a `c_void_p`, e.g. `self.obj = ctypes.c_void_p(lib.Foo_new())`.

Answer (score 3):

You've mixed tabs and spaces. It looks like your `Foo` class has a `max` method, but in fact, due to your mixed tabs and spaces, the definition of `max` is actually nested within the definition of `bar`.

Turn on "show whitespace" in your editor, so you can see this next time. Running Python with the `-tt` command-line flag will give you error messages if Python detects that you're mixing tabs and spaces, which also helps.

Comment: Yes.. error has removed but it is not calling to a function `max`. means `f.max(3,5)` should give 5, but it is returning nothing.

Comment: @Latik: but your method doesn't return anything; you've missed a `return` in your Python method. Change it to `return lib.Foo_max(self.obj)`.

Comment: @Latik, did you read the comment by @glglgl? `Foo_max` operates on the static globals `num1` and `num2`. The prototype needs to be `int Foo_max(Foo *foo, int num1, int num2)`.

Comment: sorry.. but I have changed that prototype by `int Foo_max(Foo *foo, int num1, int num2){ return foo->max(num1,num2); }` ,  but still it is returning value.

Comment: @Latik, did you also fix the Python code as @MartijnPieters suggested? Include `num1` and `num2` in the call, i.e. `return lib.Foo_max(self.obj, num1, num2)`.

Comment: @eryksun Yes I have fixed that also, I am getting output only `Hello`, means my program is able to call only function `bar`, is there any missing header file in c++ side??

Comment: @Latik, you have to print the result. In Python 2 use `print f.max(3, 5)`. In Python 3 `print` is a function, so use `print(f.max(3, 5))`.